# Reluctant and unwilling to do sometime only because

Tags: expressions

How do you say or use a word to describe that "I am accepting this unfair proposal only because I have been known you for long time".  Unwilling to accept something only based on your long relationship with the person.

Comment: Your first sentence indicates you're *willing* to accept it because of the longstanding acquaintance, but your second says you're *unwilling* to accept it for the same reason. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

"I **acquiesce to** your unfair proposal only because I have  known you for long time".

Acquiesce (Source:[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquiesce))

> to accept, comply, or submit tacitly or passively —often used with in or to

According to Google

> accept something reluctantly but without protest

Comment: "I have been known you" does not make sense. You mean "I have known you..." (or possibly "been known to you").

Comment: I just copied what the OP said and overlooked the mistake. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. @KateBunting